# Why does dividing two list items always equal zero?

Tags: python

I am trying to divide two integers that belong in a list. Whenever I divide these two integers, I get zero. No matter what integer in the list I use, I always get zero.

```
 def sideList_func():
     lengths = user_sides(6.0, 7.0, 8.0)
     sideList = []
     for i in lengths:
         sideList.append(int(i))
     return sideList


 def angles_for_triangle():
     sideList = sideList_func()
     angle = sideList[1]/sideList[2]
     return angle
```

I have tried using `//`. If I use two regular integers that are not part of this list, it works fine so I'm thinking it has to do something with my list function.

Edit: This is the user_sides

```
 def user_sides(x,y,z):
     side1 = x
     side2 = y
     side3 = z
     print(side1, side2, side3)
     return side1, side2, side3
```

Comment: What is the definition of `user_sides`?

Comment: `user_sides` is useless, by the way.

Comment: so is `sideList_func`.. just use `list` directly...

Comment: Yeah, I know, which is why I initially didn't put it up. I plan to change it later on.

Comment: As it is, `angles_for_triangle` will divide `7` by `8`, which is 0 in Python 2. That's probably the issue.

Comment: So why are you converting to `int` if you don't want an `int` result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be simplified, and the error you're getting is probably because you're using Python 2.x's integer division. Try this:

```
# this line will get your decimals back :)
from __future__ import division

def sideList_func():
     return [int(i) for i in (6.0, 7.0, 8.0)]

 def angles_for_triangle():
     sideList = sideList_func()
     return sideList[1] / sideList[2]
```

I really don't see the need for `sideList_func`, if the values are fixed and known in advance you could simply write them as `int`s to begin with:

```
sideList = [6, 7, 8]
```

By the way, all your code is simply doing this:

```
def angles_for_triangle():
    return 7 / 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer divided by integer in Python 2 is always an Integer.

```
print 5/2
```

result: 2

However, if you convert 5 to float you will get the result 2.5

```
print 5.0/2
```

result: 2.5